# Save Changes in UserForm Textbox Value as new default value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that has 29 values in text boxes that are used as parameters for a rather long formula. I have entered the current settings as the starting Values in the textbox Value & text properties. I want users to be able to change the Form parameters permanently as new startup defaults using a "save" button on the form. There are a few articles on the web demonstrating this and using those examples. I have cobbled together the code below.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
'
'----------- Save Button -------------------------------------
'
Dim VBP As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBC As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim VBD As UserForm

Set VBP = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents("Calculation_Parameters")
Set VBD = VBC.Designer

With VBD
    With .Controls("Textbox1")
        .Value = 111
        .BackColor = vbRed
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

I have tried at least 20 variations on this but no luck yet. With this code I get a "Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With Block Variable not set" error message. Debug points to the 'With .controls(Textbox1")' line as the offender. I have the "Microsoft Visual Basic For App Extensibility' reference selected. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest a bit of debugging to get closer to your issue.  Try to find out which variable isnt set, VBD or VBD.Controls.  Try stepping through in the debugger and seeing if they are both set ot objects.  For some reason one of those two isnt being set.  Maybe set VBC.Designer is returning nothing?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264339.aspx

Comment: What if the user saves an invalid parameter? Nice question (something really new to me, never thought of such a customization), but honestly I would prefer to store the custom parameters in a configuration file (distributed or automatically generated on "save" click) - so keeping data apart from the compiled code, rather than letting the user modifying your code risking to corrupt it with an invalid input.

Comment: It looks like VBD is not being set. The link you provided states "The Designer property returns Nothing if the VBComponent object doesn't have a designer". I tried Textbox, Labels, ToggleButtons and none return a value when the 'Set VBD' line runs. This is puzzling since the examples focus on modifying these controls. Still no solution, I am continueing to experiemnt.

Comment: The web page I got the example from is http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-317970.html . I had made the mistake of putting the code in the form itself, but have now moved it to a module. Now none of the set commands work. Actually this is progress.

Comment: Why not save the default values to a hidden sheet and load them on opening?

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO program library and save you list of defaults in an access db or you can simply create a master list that your userform compiles from in excel and when a value changes in the userform it modifies that item on the list.